# Probability of Specific event occuring between 2 events?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random

Forgive me beforehand for what may be a question with an obvious seolution, but I havent had statistics courses in quite some time.

I have an Excel File of approximately 3000 Events, each event has a numberdesignation attached to it (from 1-19). File looks like attached in the picture.

My question is concretely: How do i Calculate the Probability of a number occuring between two other numbers as displayed in the picture, the probability of "17" Occuring between two "18".
Also how would i calculate the probability of number x occuring between two different numbers x1 and x2 such as number 14 occuring between 12 and 19.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqjdh.png

So if anyone knows the name of the methodology/formulas i am looking for please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the random variables behind those events independent? Can the distribution be assumed to be uniform on the set $\{1,\dots,19\}$?

Comment: Also, if you say probability of number 14 occuring between 12 and 19, does this automatically imply, that you would take a 12, then go further until you find the first 19 and then consider the probability of 14 being between them?

Comment: @DimaMcGreen http://i.imgur.com/ipEJo9C.png performad a chisquare test, and here is a histogram for the entire data table. So the Distribution definitely is not uniform.

As for your question I am not sure how to answer it. I guess it would be what I am looking for or at least i would consider it. The idea is: Wait till event 12 has happened, and then wait until event 19 has happened, and then find out the probability of of 14 being between those 2 numbers in the data set, and do this for the entire dataset.

Comment: Hmmm, I never did any practical statistics :) The least you could try is the empirical distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

Without further assumptions, let $\Omega=\{1,\dots,19\}$. Let $X_i$ denote the value of the $i$-th experiment (or realisation). I guess assuming stationarity will still fit your problem.

If you are looking for $y\in\Omega$ between $x_1\in\Omega\backslash\{y\}$ and $x_2\in\Omega\backslash\{y\}$, by stationarity you can assume $X_0=x_1$ so you are looking for

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}P(X_m = x_2, X_1,\dots,X_{m-1} \in \Omega\backslash\{x_2\}, \exists i\in\{1,\dots,m-1\}: X_i=y).
$$

Depending on the distribution of your events you can simplify this.

Comment: Great, Now ill just have to figure out how to implement this into a calculation in Excel or in R. You don't happen to have experience with this by any chance?

Comment: I think without making assumptions concerning the distribution that won't work out. As said above, I don't have any experience with data... I would try to see if the empirical distribution is of any help. The state space is discrete, so your 3000 events could be sufficient to make significant estimations.

Comment: I will do some readings in one of my seven thousand mathbooks on Empirical Distribution :)

Thank you so much Dima :)